# PHP Script Time Out - Fastcgi

Tags: php, fastcgi, timeout, 500-error

I have a PHP script that times out after 7 mins.

The page then displays - 500: Internal Server Error.

I have tried to increase nginx and fastcgi timeouts but the issue remains. Also nothing shows up on the error logs.

My current settings are as follows:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf:

```
FcgidIdleTimeout 1800
FcgidProcessLifeTime 300
FcgidMaxProcesses 20
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidConnectTimeout 600
FcgidIOTimeout 2400
FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
FcgidIdleScanInterval 10
```

Should any of these settings be increased further or is there some additional settings that I need to add?

Also is there another configuration file somewhere that I need to adjust?

Comment: Do your error logs show anything interesting?

Comment: The logs show nothing at all.